# Can SharePoint 2007 install on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, sharepoint-2007, moss

I have a 32 bit Windows 7 Ultimate N, will MOSS 2007 install on it?

Answer (score 2):

[this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/05/07/running-sharepoint-on-windows-7.aspx) says you can, and shows you how.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, you'll really benefit from creating a virtual environment to host MOSS and develop against it. I highly suggest against installing it on your home O/S.

Comment: Why not install on your home OS?

Comment: Assuming he's doing this for development purposes, I like the safety net provided by having a base, reusable environment (VHD, in my case) that I can fall back on if I ever pooch my current one, which I somehow managed to do once when installing Reporting Services